# Linear map triangulizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-subspace

What's the definition of a linear map that is triangulazible? I can't find it anywhere.

In addition, I was asked to find a linear map that doesn't have any invariant sub-spaces. I know that if a map is triangulazible it does have invariant sub-spaces, from there my request on the exact definition.

Do you know of a linear map that doesn't have invariant subspaces?

Thank so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a definition:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\Bbb{F}$, and let $T:V \to V$ be linear. We say $T$ is triangualrizable over $\Bbb{F}$ if there is a basis $\beta$ of $V$ such that the matrix representation $[T]_{\beta}$ is a triangular matrix.

By the way, every linear map has invariant subspaces, namely $\{0\}$ and $V$. You're probably interested in non-trivial invariant subspaces, i.e a subspace $W$ such that $\{0\}\subsetneq W \subsetneq V$ and $T[W] \subset W$. The following theorem addresses this question:

> Let $V$ be a non-zero finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\Bbb{F}$, and $T:V \to V$ be linear. Then, $\{0\}$ and $V$ are the only $T$-invariant subspaces if and only if the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}$.

So, this tells you exactly when a linear map has no (non-trivial) invariant subspaces.

Comment: Thank you so much! How would you find the characteristic polynomial of a map? I'm able to find it only for matrices. Thanks!

Comment: @saraspagno Given a linear map $T:V \to V$, you define the charactersitc polynomial by first choosing a basis $\beta$ of $V$, and then defining it to be the char.polynomial of the matrix $[T]_{\beta}$; in symbols, $P_T(t) := P_{[T]_{\beta}}(t)$. This is definition is actually basis-independent because if $\gamma$ is another basis, then $[T]_{\beta}$ and $[T]_{\gamma}$ have the same characteristic polynomial (a standard exercise).

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is that for examples over R2, I have indeed found a base that gives a matrix with a characteristic polynomial that is irreducible over F. After that though, if I look at another base for R2, with the same map, that can gives me a triangular matrix. Which would mean the map does have an invariant subspace, doesn't it?

Comment: @saraspagno that's not possible. you made an error in computation somehwere. If in one basis, the matrix is triangular, then the characteristic polynomial splits (in particular it is reducible, i.e NOT irreducible.) Therefore, the characteristic polynomial (calculated in any other basis) also splits.

Comment: Ok, I will check my calculations again. Thank you so much for all the clarifications, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix $R(\theta)\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$

$$R (\theta)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}\right]$$
for $\theta\in(0,\pi)$, this matrix corresponds to rotation about the origin, you may check it has no invariant subspace **except** for $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, which we regard as a trivial subspaces.

For the definition of triangulazible:

> $T:V \to V$ a linear map over $V$, a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\Bbb{F}$. We say $T$ is triangualrizable over $\Bbb{F}$ if there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ such that the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ is a triangular matrix.